# Instalation of program Strange Eons

Tags: software-installation

I would like to install Strange Eons application for Ubuntu. It's on link:
https://strangeeons.cgjennings.ca/download.html
I am unable to follow readme file. I am a beginner with Ubuntu, so I need step-by-step guidance.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you read their installation steps?  http://se3docs.cgjennings.ca/um-install-other.html

Comment: Stuck in step number 2:

Comment: marinebiologist@Mietusch:~/Documents/Talisman/SE$ tar -xzf strange-eons-nix-b3970.tar.gz
tar (child): strange-eons-nix-b3970.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
marinebiologist@Mietusch:~/Documents/Talisman/SE$

Comment: Downloaded file is strange-eons-3970.tar.gz

Comment: If you downloaded the file, it is probably located in `~/Downloads`.  Go to that folder `cd ~/Downloads` then run that tar command again.

Comment: It is located in ~/Documents/Talisman/SE. I went there and ran: tar -xzf strange-eons-nix-b3970.tar.gz. The reply was: tar (child): strange-eons-nix-b3970.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: I have now downloaded both the early access and the one from 2017.  Both of them I was able to extract with simple commands of `tar xvf strange-eons-nix-b3784.tar.gz` and `tar xvf strange-eons-3970.tar.gz` and these were when I downloaded them and the went to my `~/Downloads` folder.  Did you make sure that the file is there by running `ls -al` or `ls -rtl`?

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Instead of using -xzf I used xvf, like you did. Thank you again!

Comment: Ah, so their instructions are wrong.  Interesting.  =)